# Forbid Spring Security to create new sessions on login

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, spring-session

I implemented Spring Security and Spring Session in my project. Everything is fine, but I want to find an answer: how I can forbid Spring Security to create new sessions on login?
Now it works like this: when user login `SessionDestroyedEvent` is thrown. But I don't need such behavior. I tried different `SessionCreationPolicy`, but result is the same. I hope you will help me to find out the solution.

Comment: What Servlet/Tomcat version do you have?

Comment: I use Spring Boot with Apache Tomcat/8.0.33 @holmis83